# Display Tumblr’s nested blockquotes (reblog notes) like they are displayed in the dashboard

Tags: tumblr, dashboard, tumblr-themes, blockquote

In a tumblr theme I want to adapt the way how reblog notes are displayed in the tumblr dashboard.

I want this:

[tumblr reblog notes as nested blockquotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiE4e.png)

to look like this:

[tumblr reblog notes in dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vnio.png)

---

**Any solution or idea is highly appreciated!**

This question has already been asked here:
["Unnesting" Nested Blockquotes Using jQuery (to fit tumblr's September 2015 update)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973366/unnesting-nested-blockquotes-using-jquery-to-fit-tumblrs-september-2015-upda)
but without a fiddle and I cannot comment yet.

Comment: Here’s a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6r5acv64/

Comment: You can try [this unnest plugin](http://neothm.com/post/148902138319/un-nest-tumblr-captions-a-plugin-by).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Seems to be exactly what I was searching for.